# Gunicorn 21.2.0 with Nginx shows "Mixed content" error

Tags: http, nginx, ssl, gunicorn

After upgrading Gunicorn version to 21.2.0 (the latest), my website started to show "Mixed Content" error. I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy. My current Nginx config:

```
 server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name _;

    #
    # Basic location config
    #
    location / {
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      proxy_pass http://frontend;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_real_ip;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
      proxy_hide_header X-Tm;
      proxy_hide_header X-Trace;
    }

  }
```

Maybe someone knows what could be changed?

Comment: Mixed content is caused by embedding plain HTTP resources inside a HTTPS side (as script, css, image, ...). This is not caused by the configuration of the reverse proxy (in this case nginx) since this only passes through the content. The problem is instead inside your web application (after the reverse proxy) which generates this wrong embedding information.